# Regarding the operator << for std::fstream

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

I'm having trouble trying to figure out what's causing this strange behavior.
I have a method that computes a histogram for each sub-image I have from a given image, for each sub-image I compute it's histogram and store it in a std::vector, after that I have another method that iterates through this vector and put every histogram in a std::fstream to an output file. The thing is, before my code was working perfectly, the output file had one line for each histogram with X elements per histogram. Now, a couple weeks later (without even changing anything on the code) I have the output file jumping a line for each of the X elements per histogram, giving me a gigantic file and I don't even know what is causing this strange behavior. 
Does the operator << put a newline after every element? or is it something to do with the histogram from the openCV? here are the code of the two methods.

This is the method that calculates the Histograms and store them on maskHist vector

```
void lbpd::lbpDescr::generateHistogram() {
float range[]          = {0, 255};
const float* histRange = {range};
int histSize           = 256;
bool uniform           = true; 
bool accumulate        = false; 
cv::Mat aux;

for(int i = 0; i < imgCells.size(); i++) {
    calcHist(&imgCells[i], 1, 0, cv::Mat(), aux,  1, &histSize, &histRange, uniform, accumulate);
    cv::normalize(aux, aux, 1);
    maskHist.push_back(aux);
    /*reset aux image preventing overlaping images*/
    aux = cv::Mat();
}
```

The method that is giving me headache:

```
void lbpd::lbpDescr::toFile() {
int sliceIndex = 0;
std::fstream loadToFile;

loadToFile.open ("currentImageHistogram.txt", std::fstream::out);

for(int i = 0; i < maskHist.size(); i++) {
    /*Each index of maskHist is a full histogram with X elements and even like that
      my output file is jumping one line for EACH element on every histogram*/
    loadToFile << maskHist[i];
}
loadToFile.close();
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Run your code in [the debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) that almost certainly came with your development environment (and if your development environment has no debugger, change environments to one that does) and inspect what is in `maskHist`. If you don't like what's in `maskHist`, use the debugger to find out how it got there.